# Is there a Python idiom for creating dot folders in home directory?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's an idiom for creating dot folders and files for saving config files in all operating systems using Python.

Comment: Please clarify your question, as formulated now it is unclear what you are asking. Do you ask how to find home dir with python? Or whether it is correct? Or how to create `.<name>` folders? Or what?

Comment: @alko He want to know how to create a folder which name is `.`, and some files which name are `.<name>`

Comment: I find the question clear enough:  OP wants to let his Python application use a hidden dir (typically starting with a dot) in the user's home dir, probably to store application-specific data.  I'm not aware of any library unifying such access.  I would be interested in such a thing, too.  You should consider that this might be mostly Unix-specific since on Windows systems (and maybe others) a dot-dir isn't as common or maybe even not possible.

Comment: @Alfe `.dir` folders are normal for win systems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get user folder with `os.path.expanduser`:

on Win

```
>>> import os, os.path
>>> os.path.expanduser('~')
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\alko'
```

on *nix

```
>>> os.path.expanduser('~')
'/home/alko'
```

And create dotted folder with `os.mkdir` (works on both):

```
>>> hd = os.path.expanduser('~')
>>> os.mkdir(os.path.join(hd, '.my-config'))
```

Comment: downvoter, any comments?

Comment: I think the idea is to use `os.path.expanduser('~/.my-config')`